# Deciding charset for HTTP Headers. Should i simply put utf-8 and fuggedaboutit?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, character-encoding

I was analyzing a page using Google Page Speed http://pagespeed.googlelabs.com/#url=http_3A_2F_2Fqweop.com&mobile=false&rule=SpecifyCharsetEarly

and it says that we should specify an explicit character set in HTTP Headers.

So basically my question is what determines what character set I should be using?

which character sets will have the least *size* / *fastest* ?

OR

What kind of savings can I have by using ASCII instead of say UTF-16 ?

Should i simply put utf-8 and fuggedaboutit ?

Comment: If you don't have any special requirements imposed, you can use UTF-8 in 99.9% of situations.

Comment: which character sets will have the least size / fastest ?

Comment: It doesn't really work that way. UTF-8 does encode some characters with multiple bits but the comparison doesn't make any sense in this regard. Use what fits best, and usually it's UTF-8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should include the charset that the page is encoded in. You'll want to be sure that you're telling the truth. For instance, there are a *lot* pages running around without a `charset` designation (and therefore being treated as UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1) which are actually encoded as [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). That's fine as long as you stick to character codes they have in common (certainly 32-127 and all the important control characters like newline, tab, etc.). But you start with any accented letters or special symbols, and suddenly your page doesn't look right cross-browser.

[This article on charsets and Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky is well worth a read, if you haven't already.

Comment: thank you. which character sets will have the least size / fastest ? What kind of savings can I have by using ASCII instead of say UTF-16 ?

Comment: To be precise, pages without charset designation are only treated as UTF-8 in Chrome, (most) other browsers treat those as ISO-8859-1 or similar.

Comment: @Pacerier: UTF-8 is great if most of your text is in western script, because nearly all characters you'll actually use are represented in a single byte. Make sure your tools use that charset correctly. If most of your text is in an east asian script, UTF-16 or UTF-32 are better choices, depending on which script it is.

Comment: I would like to add that it's best to check wether the software you are using for coding has an option to define the charset used to encode the page when saving the document. This way you can specify the one you want, otherwise you may end up specifying the wrong charset in the headers.

Comment: @Tatu: Thanks. Do you have a reference for that? I'm quite certain you're right, I'd just like to read more.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Actually UTF-8 can display all characters as UTF-32 so changing encoding for that matter does not have much sense.

Comment: @Petr: Yes, all of the transformations can represent all Unicode characters (that's the point of them). The issue is size. If most of your text is in an east asian script, using UTF-8 will result in a mostly three- or even four-byte characters, bloating your file size. If you use UTF-16, most of those will instead be two-byte characters, making UTF-16 the better choice. If most of your text is in a western script, UTF-8 is the better choice, because the common characters are only one byte, and the occasional east asian character will be 3 or 4, but it's occasional, so that's okay.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, I have no reference, but in our own testing I have noticed that pages encoded with ISO-8859-1 and missing the charset info work properly on all other browsers than Chrome. I assume Chrome uses UTF-8 but other browsers use whatever is the default charset for the operating system?

Comment: @T.J.: Oh, I see the point now. I wouldn't be concerned about the text size unless I have hundreds or thousands GB of pure text anyway.

Comment: @Petr: Pacerier asked what would be fastest/smallest, you see. But I think I'd care if my page took twice as long to download and cost me twice as much in data transport as it had to.

Answer (score 2):

Setting encoding in HTTP headers does not encode the page. It only **tells** browsers how the page is encoded and how they should treat it. So set the encoding in which the page is encoded.

If you want to decide which encoding to use, I would recommend UTF-8.

You can display all alphabetic characters of all languages (and much more) in UTF-8 encoding. There isn't any reason for use different encoding unless your pages need to be displayed by a device which does not support UTF-8 (such a device probably does not exist) or you have some very special requirements.

The performance impact of using different encoding is negligible as well as the page size.

Comment: just curious.. what characters canNot be rendered using UTF8?

Comment: *"The performance impact of using different encoding is negligible as well as the page size."* If you use UTF-16 to encode a text written in western script, it'll be twice as large as if you encoded it with UTF-8. (If you used UTF-32, it'd be **four times** as large.) Similarly, if you use UTF-8 to encode text primarily written in eastern asian script, it's going to be 50% to 100% larger than it would be in UTF-16.

Comment: @Pacerier: I would say none. The "almost" was just for be careful :)

Comment: @T.J. It might be a problem in some specific cases, but in most cases images and other files takes much more data transfer than the text of html page.

Comment: please expand on what **some very special requirements** would be